# pull one line at a time from text file to use as a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a PowerShell version 5 script that will query a text document, that simply has a list of usernames, and then run a series of `Get-ADUser` and `Set-ADUser` commands against each one.

I have the script working so that if I enter a single username (`$SamAccountName` is the variable that I use now for the `-Identitity` modifiers) it works great, but now I want it to run batches from a TXT file.

```
#Pull a list of users from Text file
$TXTfile = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter path to Text File'
$file = Get-Content $TXTfile
$file | foreach {
  $items = $_.Split("=")
  if ($items[0] -eq "") { $SamAccountName = $items[1] }
}

echo $SamAccountName
```

EDIT: I pulled this code from the web and tried to make it work, but it may be the wrong code, more than likely I'm missing some brackets - what can I say I'm a nube.

The error that I get is:

> Enable-ADAccount : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

My text file simply looks like this:

```
SmithA
TurnerH
SchmoJ
TrumpD
```

Here is the full script that I run for disabling individual accounts:

```
# this Powershell script will disable a users stored in a TXT file.
# along with disabling their account it will also: 
# -Strip thier Group memberships
# -Update some attributes
# -Move the account to the Disabled User's OU
#
#
$UC = Get-Credential
$Date = Get-Date
$Ticket = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input LANDesk ticket number'
#
#
#Prompt for to enter a single username:#
#$samAccountName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Username to be disabled:'
#
#

#Pull a list of users from Text file
$TXTfile = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter path to Text File'
$file = Get-Content $TXTfile
$file | foreach {
  $items = $_.Split("=")
  if ($items[0] -eq "") { $SamAccountName = $items[1] }



# Enable the account
Enable-ADAccount -Identity $samAccountName

# Remove Group Memberships
(GET-ADUSER –Identity $samAccountName –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $samAccountName 

# Update Attributes
    #Remove from main dynamic distribution list
    Set-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -company X1
    #Clear GAL field "Mail Box Type"
    Set-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Clear "extensionAttribute1"
    #Remove from team dynamic distribution list
    Set-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Department x2
    #Modify Description field with disable date and ticket number
    Set-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Description "disabled $Date Ticket $Ticket"

# Move Account 
    Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | move-adobject -targetpath "ou=disabled,ou=users,ou=division,dc=department,dc=company,dc=lcl" 

# Disable Account
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity $samAccountName

}
```

Comment: If your text file has just the usernames, why are you splitting on `=`?

Comment: Please provide examples of the contents of your input file.

Comment: @BenH - I have this nasty suspicion that he may have DNs in the file, rather than just sAMAccountNames...

Comment: How are you calling `Enable-ADAccount`? That is not in the code you are showing. Your "`echo`" should be inside your loop if you wanted to test.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin In that case OP has no need for the string split operation, `Enable-ADAccount -Identity "CN=distinguished,OU=name,DC=domain,DC=example"` is perfectly valid

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Indeed - but I wasn't going to be certain of that until I saw the input, which is why I asked for same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many problems here, you're splitting unnecessarily, not assigning `$samAccountName` unless the first part is empty which it never will be and you're not doing the work in the loop so at best it would only process the last line.

This should work, although not tested.

```
# This Powershell script will disable a users stored in a TXT file.
# Along with disabling their account it will also: 
# -Strip their group membership
# -Update some attributes
# -Move the account to the Disabled User's OU
$UC = Get-Credential
$Date = Get-Date
$Ticket = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input LANDesk ticket number'

#Pull a list of users from Text file
$TXTfile = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter path to Text File'
$samAccountNames = Get-Content $TXTfile
foreach ($samAccountName in $samAccountNames)
{
    # Enable the account
    Enable-ADAccount -Identity $samAccountName

    # Remove Group Memberships
    Get-ADUser –Identity $samAccountName –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $samAccountName 

    # Update Attributes
    #Remove from main dynamic distribution list
    Set-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -company X1
    #Clear GAL field "Mail Box Type"
    Set-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Clear "extensionAttribute1"
    #Remove from team dynamic distribution list
    Set-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Department x2
    #Modify Description field with disable date and ticket number
    Set-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Description "disabled $Date Ticket $Ticket"

    # Move Account 
    Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | move-adobject -targetpath "ou=disabled,ou=users,ou=division,dc=department,dc=company,dc=lcl" 

    # Disable Account
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity $samAccountName
}
```

Comment: That worked! Well mostly worked... I have to add -Credential $UC to the end of the string under the "# Remove Group Memberships" otherwise I got an Invalid credentials error.

Comment: Now... I am being prompted: "Are you sure you want to perform this action?" for each account with regards to removing the Group Membership. Is there a way to automatically choose the "Yes to All" option?

Comment: I figured that one out all by myself - or rather Google helped me...I added  -Confirm:$false to end of that line and it no longer prompts me.